# Print the Empty cell Adjacent cell value in Excel Sheet using Java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have an Excel sheet I need to print the adjacent cell value when I am seeing the empty cell in java.

I had written the code to print the values in the Excel sheet and I too find the empty cell but I don't how to print the adjacent cell value on seeing the empty cell

```
public class empty {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        InputStream ExcelFileToRead = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\GOMATHI\\Desktop\\data1.xls");

        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(ExcelFileToRead);
        HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        HSSFRow row;
        HSSFCell cell;

        Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();

        while (rows.hasNext()) {
            row = (HSSFRow) rows.next();
            Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();

            while (cells.hasNext()) {
                cell = (HSSFCell) cells.next();
                if (cell == null || cell.getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
                    // logic goes here. I don't know.

                    System.out.println(no);

                }
                System.out.println(cell.toString());
            }

        }
        // System.out.println();
    }
}


Input: Excel File
Id     Value
01      200
02      201
03      203
04       
05      205
```

Output:
The Value at 4th cell Value is empty so I need to print its corresponding ID.
04

Answer (score 0):

First, I think your test `if (cell == null || cell.getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK)` is half useless because `cell` should never be null.
Assuming this, you can get the cell of the previous column with `row.getCell(cell.getColumnIndex() - 1)`